# Proving $133|a^{18}-b^{18}$ if $\gcd(a,133)=\gcd(b,133)=1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

If $\gcd(a,133)=\gcd(b,133)=1$ then prove that $133|a^{18}-b^{18}$.

Using Fermat theorem: $a^{132} \equiv 1\mod\ 133$ and $b^{132} \equiv 1\mod\ 133$, so $a^{132} \equiv b^{132}\mod\ 133$. What should I do further.

Comment: Use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$133=7\cdot19$ is not prime, so you can't use Fermat's little theorem this way.

You have $a^6 \equiv 1 \mod 7$ and $a^{18} \equiv 1 \mod 19$ by Fermat's little theorem instead, since $\gcd(a,133)=1$.

So  $a^{18} \equiv 1 \mod 7$ and $a^{18} \equiv 1 \mod 19$.
Using the Chinese remainder theorem, $a^{18} \equiv 1 \mod 133$. Similiarly, $b^{18} \equiv 1 \mod 133$, since also $\gcd(b,133)=1$, so $$a^{18}-b^{18} \equiv 1-1 =0 \mod 133$$

Hence $133 \mid a^{18}-b^{18} $ for all $a,b$ such that $\gcd(a,133)=1$ and $\gcd(b,133)=1$.

Comment: Sorry but could you explain how you got $a^{18} \equiv 1 \mod 7$ from $a^6 \equiv 1 \mod 7$?

Comment: @Airdish $a^{18} = (a^6)^3 \equiv 1^3 = 1 \mod 7$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)